# For what value(s) of $k$ is $f$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

For what value(s) of $k$  is $f$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Define $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. via 
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} c @{} l @{} }
\\[1ex]
&f(x) &{}=\displaystyle
\begin{cases}
\frac{10x^2-16x-8}{x-2} &\text{if } x \neq 2 \\
k &\text{if } x=2
\end{cases}
\end{array}

So i was able to see that the $$\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)=24$$. so does that mean k must be 24?

Comment: Yes. An equivalence of continuity is "$f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = f(p).$

Comment: i was confused on this part. is k=p or 2=p in this case

Comment: $p=2$ and $f(p)=k$

Comment: In this case, $p=2$ and $k=f(2)=f(p)$ must be $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)=24$ to $f$ be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes k must be 24 for the function to be continuous. It is the definition of continuity: A function is continuous if the limit of its value as x approaches a point is equal to the value of the function at that point, or, in notation, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow p}{f(x)}=f(p)$$